# Getting control name in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there any way to take `<someControl>` name to a string format variable programically?

For example:

```
<Canvas Name="zem">
    <Image Name="pav_kelias" />
</Canvas>
```

C#:

```
Image pav = new Image();
pav = (Image)zem.Children[0];
```

Now I linked my `<Image>` and I want to get it's name - "pav_kelias".

> Am I right ? :

```
string name = pav.Name;
```

When I try this my program crash.

Comment: Any exception message?

Comment: I setup a small project and call your c# code in a `Loaded` event of the window and this is working as expected. Where do you call `pav.Name` ?

Comment: One of the most frequently accessed WPF questions concerns finding controls by name and type - reference it for help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type

Comment: @armandasalmd it depends when you do it. If before `InitializeComponents()` is called then it will crash, if after then it should be fine

Comment: And note that `Image pav = new Image();` is useless. Just write `Image pav = (Image)zem.Children[0];` or `var pav = (Image)zem.Children[0];`.